# How to show a stock panorama activity with action bar

Tags: android

Need help on something I have tried doing since the last few days.

I am trying to open an image using the Google Panorama API

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle){
        Panorama.PanoramaApi.loadPanoramaInfo(GOOGLE_CLIENT,Uri.parse(url)).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<PanoramaApi.PanoramaResult>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(PanoramaApi.PanoramaResult result){
                        if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                            Intent intent = result.getViewerIntent();
                            if (intent != null){
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

I have the above code to open up the panorama in the url. This all works but I cannot get any API in Google's Play Services arsenal to open the panorama image in a fragment or add an action bar to the opened activity as I dont have any control over it.

It would be really helpful if someone could point me in the right direction?

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/panorama/package-summary.html

Comment: I am using a similar code, but getting result.getViewerIntent() as null. The documentation says it happens if the image is not panorama, but I clicked it using Nexus 5 Camera with panorama mode. Any clues ?

Comment: Check the same image's metadata.. Does it have the required metadata for the viewer to recognize it as a panorama

Comment: Hi, since I also want to adjust the panorma activity (show some UI elements) I'm wondering if you have found a solution to your problem in the meantime. I have asked a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/41172495/2011622. Maybe you can help me.